# "live" meaning in "The stock market has been...where most of Wall Street lived."

Tags: word-meaning

> The stock market had been, from the very beginning, where most of Wall Street **lived**.—*The Big Short: Inside the Doomsday Machine* by Michael Lewis—

Hello, I searched for the meaning of "live" in this sentence. And I wondered which one is used in a sentence from two of the meanings.

> 1. Remain alive.(Lexico Dictionary)
>
> 1.3 Supply oneself with the means of subsistence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed some more meanings of 'live', including 'occupy a place'. Literally, "where I live" means 'the place where my home is located'. In North American slang, it means, figuratively, 'the mental place most important to me'. A musician might say 'music is where I live'. Most of the businesses of Wall Street, says the author, were devoted to the stock market.